# create a new tr after every 3rd td

Tags: jquery, loops

Dynamically create a TR which can only contain 3 TD's. so, if i have 6 elements then two TR's will get generated. I have written some loose code here. Please rectify.

Thanks in advance.

```
while(j<=6) {

        $('#table tbody').append('<tr><tr>');
            for(var k=0; k<3; k++) {
                var divData = '<td><article><div><span onmouseover="navigateDressMe(this,$(this).parent());" onclick="navigateFromTRA($(this).parent().find("a"));" style="cursor: pointer;"><img style="width:200px;border-width:0px;" src="/resources/images/'+StrVideoJsonOBj.tableVideo[k].SmallImageURL+'" title="'+StrVideoJsonOBj.tableVideo[k].Title+'"></span><p><a title="El congelador, tu mejor aliado en la cocina" href="">'+StrVideoJsonOBj.tableVideo[k].Title+'</a><span>&nbsp;</span>Aprovecha el congelador para ahorrar tiempo en la cocina y conservar bien tus alimentos</p><a href=""></a></div></article></td>';

                $('#table tbody tr').append(divData);
                j = j+3;

            }




        }
```

Comment: `$('#table tbody tr').append(divData);` will append `divData` to **all** rows in the table.

Comment: @BoltClock code block is updated. Actually, i am getting data from JSON object. So a new <tr> after every 3 <td>. Can you please help with the code

Answer (score 1):

The % operator is the right choice, you just need to rethink your logic there.

Every third row is when k % 3 will be 0, that is when you want to print a new tr.
Every other k you will want to add one of your td's.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to append it to the last inserted TR, so do this:

```
$('#table tbody tr:last').append(divData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the table's structure by using one loop for rows and a nested one for columns:

```
$(function () {
     var $table = $('#table tbody');
     var maxRow = 2;
     var maxCol = 3;
     for (var row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
        $table.append('<tr></tr>');
        $row = $('#table tr:last');
        for (var col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
            $row.append('<td>row '  + row + ' column ' + col +'</td>');
        }
    }
});
```